# Best way to get a list of locations in a select drop down list with options

Tags: javascript, html, location

Ok so first I am sorry if this question has been asked I searched on here for something similar but couldn't find exactly what I am looking for. So what I am trying to do is get a list of locations in a drop down list so users can choose there location and view content based on there location. I want all provinces and cities within each province(This is canada only).

So my current idea is to manually type each province and major cities within each province just a small ex:

```
<select placeholder='location'>
    <optgroup label='New Brunswick'>
        <option value='all_new_brunswick'>All of New Brunswick</option>
        <option value='moncton'>Moncton</option>
        etc...
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label='Alberta'>
       <option value='all_alberta'>All of Alberta</option>
       <option value='calgary'>Calgary</option> 
       etc..
    </optgroup> 
</select>
```

So I type each province then within each province I add a list of major cities(high populations) only. While typing all this out I realized how much work just adding the major cities is. and I am thinking what a user will think if there city is not listed. So Is there a better way to go at it? I really don't want to spend money on an API(not much free apis to get a users location also not always accurate as getting a user to choose themselves).

My other idea is if there is a free geolocation where I can fetch a users location then add that to a database every time someone with a new location signs on to my site. Then use that data to display in a drop down list and a user can choose the location they want to search in(if they don't want to search there city).

Anyone that can shed some light on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Indeed they have come up with some free APIs [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194239/free-api-or-database-for-continent-country-city-region-state) ifyou want to have a look. And, personally, I would not accept the users' own input because it is prone to become unmanageable very soon. And even if I do, I'd not directly add user input cities without checking its validity by myself. That's what I can say.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll have a look

Comment: I had a good look at those apis and others and there not exactly what I am looking for still. Would you say manually typing in the cities be the way to go about this ?  I really can't come up with any other way. I think just including the major cities is the way to go cause at the very least if there city is not listed I could add an option for them to request a city to be added. When a user adds a product I want them to select target audience location from a drop down then when they are searching products they can choose the city they wish to search in the dropdown.

Comment: I'd add records into my kept cities/countries/etc indeed as a last solution, but after I validate it. Let's say you have `Prague` in your db and a user enters `Praha`: they're the same! That causes a dupe and I, then, would not directly add anything the user enters as a location db. But, after all, it is up to you. I cannot say any way is the best or the worst.